# MYSQL: Add a column to result which contains whether this rows contain max number of a particular column or not

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL 5.7 and My Table is:

| cp_id | cp_name | cp_version | cp_parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | playlist1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | playlist1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | playlist1 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | playlist2 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | playlist2 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | playlist3 | 1 | 6 |
| 7 | playlist3 | 2 | 6 |
| 8 | playlist3 | 3 | 6 |
| 9 | playlist4 | 1 | 9 |

As you can see from the table that:

1. A single playlist can have more than one version but will have the same parent id.

Result I Require is:
I want to add a column to the result which contains whether that row is the cp version row or not.

| cp_id | cp_name | cp_version | cp_parent_id | max_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | playlist1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | playlist1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | playlist1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | playlist2 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | playlist2 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | playlist3 | 1 | 6 | 0 |
| 7 | playlist3 | 2 | 6 | 0 |
| 8 | playlist3 | 3 | 6 | 1 |
| 9 | playlist4 | 1 | 9 | 1 |

Thanks, In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+ we can use `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT *, MAX(cp_version) OVER (PARTITION BY cp_parent_id) = cp_verson AS max_version
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY cp_id;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL we can use a join approach:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.cp_version_max = t1.cp_version AS max_version
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cp_parent_id, MAX(cp_version) AS cp_version_max
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY cp_parent_id
) t2
    ON t2.cp_parent_id = t1.cp_parent_id
ORDER BY
    t1.cp_id;
```

Comment: This will work for a 2-level structure at most.

Comment: thanks, but I am working on Mysql 5.7. Do you have any answer for that?

Comment: @AmitRathod You need to tell that is for MySQL 5.7. Most people use 8.x nowadays.

Comment: @AmitRathod I have updated with a version which should work on MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Edited the Question @TheImpaler

Comment: Seriously Tim, I'm surprised to see you here. What time is it there?

Comment: @TheImpaler It is past 1am.  I will have serious focus problems while coding tomorrow morning.